# Selenium C# Assert Failing But is Valid

Tags: c#, selenium

Ok I am missing something here. My assert is failing but looking at locals, my value and return match. Tired of looking at this. What am I missing?

Code:

```
        List<String> item = new List<string>();
        // grab the cells that contain the popsockets you want to sort
        IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = Driver.FindElements_byXpath("//h2[@class='link']/a");

        // loop through the popsockets and assign the price into the ArrayList
        foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
        {
            item.Add(cell.Text);
            Assert.IsTrue(item.Contains(value));
        }
```

Locals:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `.contains()` on the list itself, not the items in the list. So it's looking for the reference to the value rather than the word.

```
Assert.IsTrue(item.Any(itm => itm.Contains(value)));
```

See [List.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: That works. Appreciate it. My work around was creating a substring which worked but your solution is cleaner.